# Loop through file and execute an api request

Tags: python, api, loops, batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to write a web service in Python (fairly new to it). I have acces to an API that wants an url in a specific format:

```
http://api.company-x.com/api/publickey/string/0/json
```

It is not a problem to perform a GET-request one by one but I would like to do it in a batch. So I have a text-file with strings in it. For example:

```
string1,
string2,
string3,
```

I would like to write a Python-script that iterates through that file, makes it in the specific format, performs the requests and writes the responses of the batch to a new text-file. I've read the docs of requests and it mentioned adding parameters to your url but it doesn't do it in the specific format I need for this API.

My basic code so far without the loop looks like this:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://api.company-x.com/api/publickey/string/0/json')

print(r.url)
data = r.text

text_file = open("file.txt", "w")
text_file.write(data)
text_file.close()
```

Comment: In what format do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've played around some more and this is what I wanted:

```
#requests to talk easily with API's
import requests

#to use strip to remove spaces in textfiles.
import sys

#two variables to squeeze a string between these two so it will become a full uri
part1 = 'http://api.companyx.com/api/productkey/'
part2 = '/precision/format'

#open the outputfile before the for loop
text_file = open("uri.txt", "w")

#open the file which contains the strings
with open('strings.txt', 'r') as f:
for i in f:    
    uri = part1 + i.strip(' \n\t') + part2
    print uri
    text_file.write(uri)
    text_file.write("\n")

text_file.close()

#open a new file textfile for saving the responses from the api
text_file = open("responses.txt", "w")

#send every uri to the api and write the respsones to a textfile
with open('uri.txt', 'r') as f2:
   for i in f2:
     uri = i.strip(' \n\t')
     batch = requests.get(i)
     data = batch.text
     print data
     text_file.write(data)
     text_file.write('\n')

text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

First open the file that has the strings,

```
import requests

with open(filename) as file:
    data = file.read()
split_data = data.split(',')
```

Then iterate through the list,

```
for string in split_data:
    r = requests.get(string)
    (...your code...)
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you for help, it guided me towards the answer!